# Make a column positive only

Tags: sql, ms-access, rdbms

Happy new year everyone. I will ask my last question for this evening.

I was wondering if it's possible in MS Access to make a column positive only. Since my approach of getting the exact number will only work if the column is >0. So when a number is <0 I want it to be 0 or 'notthing'

This is the whole code

```
(((([Factuur]![EindKMStand]-[Factuur]![BeginKMStand])-([Factuur]![Dagen]*125))*[Prijzen]![ExtraKM])+([Prijzen]![dag125KM]*[Factuur]![Dagen])) AS TotaalPrijs
```

This part have to be 0> or =0

```
((([Factuur]![EindKMStand]-[Factuur]![BeginKMStand])-([Factuur]![Dagen]*125))
```

is there a way to do this easily?

My whole query code:

```
SELECT 
SUM(A.TotaalPrijs) As TotaalPrijs,
A.AutoNR,
A.AutoKlasse,
MAX(Factuur.Dagen) as Dagen,
Prijzen.dag125KM as PrijsPerDag,
Prijzen.ExtraKM As PrijsPerExtraKM,
Factuur.FactuurNR,
Factuur.KlantNR,
Factuur.Begindatum,
Factuur.Einddatum,
Factuur.Borg,
Gegevens.voorletters,
Gegevens.tussenvoegsel,
Gegevens.achternaam,
Gegevens.straatnaam,
Gegevens.huisNR,
Gegevens.Postcode,
Gegevens.rekeningNR,
Gegevens.Plaats,
A.KMteVEEL
FROM
(SELECT Factuur.Dagen, Factuur.AutoNR AS carNR, autos.AutoNR, autos.Klasse AS AutoKlasse, Prijzen.Klasse, Prijzen.dag125KM, Prijzen.ExtraKM, (prijzen.dag125KM*Factuur.Dagen) AS MinPrijs, Factuur.FactuurNR, Factuur.KlantNR, Factuur.Begindatum, Factuur.Einddatum, Factuur.Borg, (((([Factuur]![EindKMStand]-[Factuur]![BeginKMStand])-([Factuur]![Dagen]*125))*[Prijzen]![ExtraKM])+([Prijzen]![dag125KM]*[Factuur]![Dagen])) AS TotaalPrijs, Gegevens.voorletters, Gegevens.tussenvoegsel, Gegevens.achternaam, Gegevens.straatnaam, Gegevens.huisNR, Gegevens.Postcode, Gegevens.rekeningNR, Gegevens.Plaats, (([Factuur]![EindKMStand]-[Factuur]![BeginKMStand])-Dagen*125) AS KMteVEEL
 FROM autos, Factuur, Prijzen, Gegevens
    WHERE (((Factuur.AutoNR)=Autos.AutoNR) And ((autos.Klasse)=Prijzen.Klasse) And ((Factuur.KlantNR)=Gegevens.KlantNR))

) AS A

GROUP BY 
    A.AutoNR, A.AutoKlasse, Prijzen.dag125KM, Prijzen.ExtraKM, Factuur.FactuurNR, Factuur.KlantNR, Factuur.Begindatum, Factuur.Einddatum, Factuur.Borg, Gegevens.voorletters, Gegevens.tussenvoegsel, Gegevens.achternaam, Gegevens.straatnaam, Gegevens.huisNR, Gegevens.Postcode, Gegevens.rekeningNR, Gegevens.Plaats, A.KMteVEEL
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27740624/making-formula-positive-only-ms-access

Answer (score 1):

You can use `iif()`:

```
iif(((([Factuur]![EindKMStand]-[Factuur]![BeginKMStand])-([Factuur]![Dagen]*125)) < 0, 0
    ((([Factuur]![EindKMStand]-[Factuur]![BeginKMStand])-([Factuur]![Dagen]*125))
   )
```

Comment: Sorry for my stupidness but how can I add this in my code? Can you please edit your post with the whole query in it? I would really really appriciate it!